# Azure function suddenly starts using a new IP address not specified under properties

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have whitelisted all the IPs under my functionapp to access a KeyVault with Managed Identity. I know that the MI works, because when I turn off the IP filtering, I can access the secrets. Using the IP filtering has worked in my other environments. I checked the logs of the KV to check the last IP addresses that had tried to access my KV, and saw a new IP address I hadn't seen before. Adding that IP address fixed the problem. However, this IP doesn't show up under my Functionapp properties. So is filtering IPs based on the function app properties not a viable solution anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions are subject to Outbound IP changes depending on the consumption plan you use - see [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#outbound-ip-address-changes) - for scaling purposes.

You might have to whitelist the whole Outbound IP range (which is not the most secure way of doing of course.., attackers can come from Azure as well!) or use [VNet NAT gateway mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway) or [App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).

Comment: But I'm not scaling the function. Even if I did, shouldn't the Outbound list be updated?

Comment: Its all about autoscaling - it might scale out but also scale in without you asking for it. Other customers might need the IP address you are currently using, etc. What is the consumption plan for your Function ?

Comment: Have you added the ```possibleOutboundIpAddresses``` IPs as well ? Otherwise you might need to consider adding all possible IPs for the service - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#data-center-outbound-ip-addresses - which is again, not the most secured way..

Comment: I have added all the possible ones as well. But I'm using Basic for this specific env, so this is weird behavior. But considering that my production env is using premium, I just might have to use a VNET here. Thanks for the help